# Error when uploading app to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, swift-package-manager

When I try to upload my App to App Store Connect, I get the following error under Xcode 12.4:

> Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

I think it is a Firebase bug when using the Swift Package Manager. Is there a workaround to keep using SPM without the error message?

The Error Message

[image]

I think it is a Firebase bug when using the Swift Package Manager. Is there a workaround to keep using SPM without the error message?

Comment: same here :-( using Swiftui

Comment: I added Firebase manually now

Comment: Xcode 12.5 does not produce this problem

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone who is encountering this issue,
check below link! Finally Solved problem.
[Github Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472#issuecomment-694449182)